# Does $\int_V f(s)ds=\int_U f(\varphi (t))|\det \varphi '(t))|dt$ hold if $f$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\varphi :U\to V$ a diffeomorphism where $U,V$ are open. If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a Borel function integrable function, we have that $$\int_V f(s)ds=\int_U f(\varphi (t))|\det \varphi '(t)|dt.$$

Does this formulae still hold if $f$ is Lebesgue measurable and not only a Borel function ?

Comment: Yes. A reference is Theorem 7.26 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, page 153.

Comment: The formula holds for measurable functions $f$ provided the "change of variables" $\varphi$ belongs to a well defined class of mappings, so wide that includes many non-differentiable mappings and thus for every diffeomorphisms. For the details, see [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060597/change-of-variable-formula-for-a-non-differentiable-mapping/3064072#3064072).